# R:ensuring legend colors match the defined colors

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, legend

I am using the R programming language. Using the famous Iris dataset, I created the following plot:

```
require(MASS)
cols = c('red', 'green', 'blue')
parcoord(iris[ ,-5], col = cols[iris$Species])
```

From here, I tried to add a legend:

```
legend("topright", c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), lwd = 2, col = iris$Species, bty = "n")
```

How can I ensure that the legend colors actually match the colors on the graph? Does R automatically do this?

Thanks

Comment: also use the index of your color vector in your legend: `col = cols[unique(iris$Species)]`

Comment: @user12728748, post your comment as an answer please ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the `Species` column of `iris` is a factor (try running `class(iris$Species)`). If you then run `levels(iris$Species)`, you will see that the order of the levels is `setosa versicolor virginica`.

If you convert this factor to an integer value (try `as.integer(iris$Species)`), you will see that `setosa` = 1, `versicolor` = 2, and `virginica` = 3. When you pass `cols[iris$Species]` as an argument to `parcoord()`, you are using this factor as an index, and R silently converts it to an integer vector. Hence, `setosa` will map to the first element of `cols`, namely `'red'`, and so on.

Please see below:

```
require(MASS)
cols = c('red', 'green', 'blue')
parcoord(iris[ ,-5], col = cols[iris$Species])
legend("topright", levels(iris$Species), lwd = 2, col = cols, inset = 0.05)
```

This will produce the following plot:

[image: Plot of iris data produced by above code.]

While base R graphics may be sufficient for your use case, I highly recommend exploring the `ggplot2` package for more advanced and customizable graphics.

Answer (score 1):

`iris$Species` is a factor with 3 (integer) levels and associated names:

```r
require(MASS)
str(iris$Species)
#>  Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Thus, using `cols[iris$Species]` assigns colors based on the factor level, with setosa being the first (red), etc..

You could relevel the factor, which would affect the association of the colors with the species and change the colors (setosa would be 2, hence green), to demonstrate this effect:

```r
iris$Species <- relevel(iris$Species, "versicolor")
str(iris$Species)
#>  Factor w/ 3 levels "versicolor","setosa",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

The legend only shows the 3 names and colors, so you could use the factor levels and associated names to make sure they match. Since we changed the order here, this is what we get:

```r
require(MASS)
cols = c('red', 'green', 'blue')
iris$Species <- relevel(iris$Species, "versicolor")
parcoord(iris[ ,-5], col = cols[iris$Species])
legend("top", levels(iris$Species), lwd = 2, col = cols, bty = "n")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>